# React-Native: Create a new TextInput line on enter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was wondering how I would go about creating a new TextInput line when I press enter. So like you would have with a checklist. Something like this:

- [TextInput line one]

and when I press on enter

- [TextInput line one]
- [TextInput line two with focus]

Another enter

- [TextInput line one]
- [TextInput line two]
- [TextInput line three with focus etc]

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an acceptable solution for you. I have used currying to create dynamic handler for `TextInput` event listener. You can check my solution online on this  [link](https://snack.expo.io/S1aQt5Mw4).

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    inputValues: [''],
    currentIndex: 0
  }
  inputRefs = []

  handleSubmitEditting = index => () => {
    if (this.state.inputValues[index + 1] === undefined) {
      this.setState({
        currentIndex: this.state.currentIndex + 1,
        inputValues: [...this.state.inputValues, ''] // mutate state (inputValues) & add an empty string
      })
    } else {
      const ref = this.inputRefs[index + 1]
      this.setState({
        currentIndex: index + 1
      }, () => {
        if (ref) {
          ref.focus();
        }
      })
    }
  }

  handleChangeText = index => rawText => {
    const nextInputValues = [...this.state.inputValues] // always mutate state
    nextInputValues[index] = rawText.replace('\n', '')
    this.setState({ inputValues: nextInputValues  })
  }

  handleRef = index => ref => {
    this.inputRefs[index] = ref
    if (index === this.state.currentIndex && ref && !ref.isFocused()) {
      ref.focus();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { inputValues } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        {inputValues.map((value, index) => (
          <TextInput
            key={index}
            ref={this.handleRef(index)}
            value={value}
            onSubmitEditting={this.handleSubmitEditting(index)}
            onChangeText={this.handleChangeText(index)}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for cleaning this up too :-)

Comment: I have also added an onFocus event where I just call ```setState({currentIndex: index})```